# Using Illustrator CC one layer shape out of multiple paths

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, shapes, pathfinder

I have a shape created in Photoshop (one layer)
I copy the shape to illustrator (selecting compound path)and it shows each element as a separate path.
I would like to generate a font icon so I need one path for the selected shape.
I have tried the Phathfinder --> unite - still get separated paths.
Please help me to find the way for generating one path shape.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Depending upon the artwork, it *may* be possible to reduce all the paths into a single object rather than separate objects.

- Select All
- Choose `Object > Compound Path > Make` from the menu

This *should* convert your group of separate objects into a single compound shape and thus a single object.

Using a Compound path will not necessarily work in every instance, but it will for this artwork.

---

It is important to realize that the Layers Panel in Illustrator is *actually* a "layers and objects" panel. Each Layer in Illustrator contains objects, the panel will show the *objects*. Objects are *not* the same as Layers.

You can, choose `Panel Options..` from the Layer Panel menu in Illustrator and tick the `Top Level Only` option if you wish to *only* see layers. But that will merely change what you *see* not how AI constructs things.

In other words, the panel is showing you the underlying *construction* of the layer, which normal.

Comment: There is actually no reason why the panel couldnt show also sub objects of compound paths... Or even vertices themselves. Wheter you see them as separate or one is just a question of ones own mental modeling. I mean technically any curve with more than one segment is just multiple segments stringed together.